# How to properly define a method for an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

How to correctly define a method for an object in JavaScript? The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#The_methods) shows example with prototype:

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");

// call the Person sayHello method.
person1.sayHello(); // logs "Hello, I'm Alice"
```

But why I need to add methods outside the constructor if I can add it inside of it using `this`:

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;

    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
    };
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");

// call the Person sayHello method.
person1.sayHello(); // logs "Hello, I'm Alice"
```

Are there any reasons to define method via prototype? And what the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Prototypes allow more effective object creation because prototype methods are shared and not recreated like in case of methods defined as own properties inside of constructor. So if you plan to have multiple instances of the Person then you should use prototype-way.

Comment: Checkout answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript) questions it will cover your question too.

Comment: @dfsq It makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: i am new in computer science.. if u r using jquery.. then maybe protoype can be call like this $.fn.methodname =function(){}

Comment: Thanks to all, guys!